# HTML 5 video in IE says "invalid source"

Tags: internet-explorer, video, html5-video

I'm struggling to debug an odd issue we're having. We have two web sites (two different URLs...) that both use the video tag to load a video from the same (respective) domain. This works in all browsers except IE. IE can play one of the videos just fine, the other shows up as "invalid source" when rendered.

I've eliminated some of the common issues that are related to this (making sure we have the IE compatibility mode meta tag, make sure it's using a supported codec, etc) but none have seemed to be the culprit.

The video formats are nearly identical, but with some slight differences. Wondering if the issue could be one of these slight differences...or possibly an issue on the server side (maybe a MIME type issue?)

The video that works in IE:

- mp4 file
- H.264 codec
- 1920 x 1080 resolution
- ~4mb file size

The video that does not work in IE:

- mp4 file
- H.264 codec (with AAC audio)
- 1706 x 720 resolution
- ~12mb file size

I should mention that the video that isn't working in IE isn't unique to that video...it's all videos on that particular site. Which makes me think it could be a server level issue of some sort.

Other than that, the only real difference is that one was encoded with audio (could that be the issue?).

Answer (score 0):

It might be a MIME type issue. Please refer to the **Remarks** of [this documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/hh772923%28v=vs.71%29?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> Beginning with Windows Internet Explorer 9, any audio or video content needs the correct mime type set on the server, or the files won't play. Internet Explorer 9 supports MP3 audio, and MP4 audio and video. The following table shows the required settings for your web server to host these files correctly.

[image]

You could refer to the above table and check the Mime type settings.